# How go to maximum index when click the button back to 0 index and reverse with the button next

Tags: android

*I'm creating an app on android for viewing the image with the sound when I select the next button to show the new image and the back button to show previous image but when the press the next button to the maximum index , i want it to show the start from first image index and when the press the back button to the minimum index, i want it to show the start from maximum image index. I have problem when i click the back button go to 0 index i want it show the image from the final index and also when i click the next button go to final index i want it show the from the 0 index.* **But when i click back button nothing happen what i have to do with Back Button**

```
 public void btn_click(View v){
     if (v == btn_next){
            if((IMAGE_IDS.length)> currentimageindex){
                try{
                imageview.setImageResource(IMAGE_IDS[currentimageindex]);
                   mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, myMusic[currentsoundindex]);
                   mp.start();
                  currentimageindex = (currentimageindex + 1) % IMAGE_IDS.length;
                  currentsoundindex = (currentsoundindex + 1) % myMusic.length;
                }
            catch(Exception e){
           Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), e.getMessage(),  Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
               }
              if((IMAGE_IDS.length)== currentimageindex){
                    try{
                        imageview.setImageResource(IMAGE_IDS[currentimageindex=0]);
                           mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, myMusic[currentsoundindex=0]);
                           mp.start();
                           currentimageindex = (currentimageindex + 1) % IMAGE_IDS.length;
                           currentsoundindex = (currentsoundindex + 1) % myMusic.length;
                        }
                    catch(Exception e){
                   Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), e.getMessage(),  Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }                 
              }
        if (v == btn_back) {
            if(currentimageindex!=0){
                try{
                imageview.setImageResource(IMAGE_IDS[currentimageindex]);
                   mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, myMusic[currentsoundindex]);
                   mp.start();
                      currentimageindex = (currentimageindex + IMAGE_IDS.length -1) % IMAGE_IDS.length;
                      currentsoundindex = (currentsoundindex + myMusic.length -1) % myMusic.length;
                }
            catch(Exception e){
           Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), e.getMessage(),  Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
               }
            if((currentimageindex)==0){
                try{
                      imageview.setImageResource(IMAGE_IDS[currentimageindex]);
                       mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, myMusic[currentsoundindex]);
                       mp.start();                  
                      currentimageindex = (currentimageindex + IMAGE_IDS.length -1) % IMAGE_IDS.length;
                      currentsoundindex = (currentsoundindex + myMusic.length -1) % myMusic.length;
                    }
                catch(Exception e){
                   Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), e.getMessage(),  Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                }
          }
```

Answer (score 1):

For the back button

```
      if((currentimageindex)==0){
               currentimageindex= IMAGE_IDS.length-1;
               currentsoundindex= myMusic.length-1;
              imageview.setImageResource(IMAGE_IDS[currentimageindex]);
               mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, myMusic[currentsoundindex]);
               mp.start();
      }
```

For the next button

```
      if((currentimageindex)==IMAGE_IDS.length){
               currentimageindex= 0;
               currentsoundindex= 0;
              imageview.setImageResource(IMAGE_IDS[currentimageindex]);
               mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, myMusic[currentsoundindex]);
               mp.start();
      }
```

Hope this will help.